# How to access array from another method in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, methods

How to access array from another method in this example? I'm new in c# and i really appreciate if you will help me. Thanks in advance!

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
     int[] array1 = new int[5];
     for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
         array1[i] = i;
     }
 }
 private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
     int[] array2 = new int[5];
     for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
         array2[i] = array1[i];
     }
 }
```

Comment: This isn't really anything to do with arrays - it's variables in general. Currently you've got *local* variables, which are only part of the state of the method. If you want the state to be for the whole *object*, the variable needs to be declared as an instance variable. I suggest you look at whatever book or tutorial you're using to learn the language, and see what it says about instance variables, which are also known as fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Jon Skeet mentioned in his comment, local variables are by definition local to the method which defines them. If you want something to be visible globally, you need to make it an instance variable, or return it from the method.

Assuming that only `array1` needs to be visible, it suffices to declare that one outside.

```
// Declare the array globally.
int[] array1 = new int[5];
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Initially the array inside this method.
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
        array1[i]=i;
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int[] array2 = new int[5];
    // Copy from the global array
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        array2[i]=array1[1];
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Declare both arrays outside to enable access.

```
 int[] array1, array2;
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
     array1 = new int[5];
     for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
         array1[i] = i;
     }
 }
 private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
     array2 = new int[5];
     for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
         array2[i] = array1[i];
     }
 }
```